# How to reshape dataframe and transpose recurring columns to dataframe rows?

Tags: r, aggregate, reshape, transpose

I have a dataframe that has recurring columns (the interval is 5).

[my dataframe at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJTwp.png)

So this is how it looks: I have 5 type of columns and they repeat time over time. The recurring columns have a suffix in their name, this can be removed/renamed as well, so that they would all match.

What I would like to do is to transpose these recurring columns to rows, so that I would have only 5 columns in the end (Dates, PX_LAST, PX_HIGH, PX_VOLUME, Name). Then I would be able to group the dataframe by Dates, Name etc and do many other things.

I tried some manipulations with pipe operator  %>%, but it didn't really work at the moment. Since I don't have any ideas left, I thought, that maybe you could help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example with `dput` and expected output

Comment: dft <- data.frame("Date" = 1:2, "Age" = c(21,15), "Date" = 1:2, "Age" = c(32,12))  ....
dft2 <- data.frame("Date" = c(1,2,1,2), "Age" = c(21,15,32,12))

Comment: Are these two different datasets or a single one?

Comment: Can you try with the solution posted below (assuming that it is a single dataset

Comment: Like the first one is the current situation, what I have at the moment. And the other one is how I ideally want my dataframe to be. These two are just random examples of how I would like it to look.

Comment: Yes, it's a single dataset

Comment: @akrun It throws an errror at the moment: Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match

Comment: I updated the solution based on the data you showed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to `split` the data into a `list` of data.frame based on the column names and then `rbind` them together

```
nm1 <-  sub("\\.\\d+", "", names(dft))
i1 <- ave(seq_along(dft), nm1, FUN = seq_along)
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split.default(dft, i1), 
      function(x) setNames(x, sub("\\.\\d+", "", names(x)))))
row.names(out) <- NULL
out
#  Date Age
#1    1  21
#2    2  15
#3    1  32
#4    2  12
```

---

Or another option is to loop through the `unique` names, subset the data, `unlist`, and convert to `data.frame`

```
un1 <- unique(nm1)
setNames(data.frame(lapply(un1, 
       function(x) unlist(dft[grep(x, names(dft))]))), un1)
```

#### data

```
dft <- data.frame("Date" = 1:2, "Age" = c(21,15), "Date" = 1:2, "Age" = c(32,12))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! These both work. At first it didn't but I have some kind of issue with my own dataframe, but when I only selected a few columns then it worked. Thanks man!!

Comment: @Martiiin  Probably, there is slight changes in name other than the numbers at the end